# Error when importing a new project in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

This is what I get when I import a new project:

`Gradle 'TestingNiftyDialog' project refresh failed`

```
Error:Could not initialize class org.gradle.util.GradleVersion
```

[image]

And in gradle:
[image]

[image]

When I move the mouse over `dependencies {...}` it says: 
`dependencies cannot be applied to (groovy.lang.Closure)`

This is the project that i'm trying to import : https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip 
( I also tried to import other projects but I get the same error)

**Update** - I just noticed that the error shows also when I create a new project...

Comment: I know nothing about Idea, but a (very) wild guess: is `$GROOVY_HOME` correctly set?

Comment: I will take a look at that after I finish reinstalling android studio.

Comment: I just finished reinstalling Android Studio. The previous error is gone but now I get this: `Gradle 'NiftyDialogEffects-master' project refresh failed` and `Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.`

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Nope, I'm not using a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I deleted all `.gradle/build` directories from within the project and that seemed to clear it up nicely.

Perhaps because the imported project is trying to use a .gradle cache created by another version and failing?